# Two DrawerLayout in same direction within one activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, user-interface

Here is my activity xml file with one drawerlayout. how can i add second drawer with same gravity, i mean two drawer layout with same gravity `android:layout_gravity="end"`,

i have requirement to show one more view with slide animation.

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end" >

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview_filter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
               />
        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: How will these drawers be activated? Swiping again after first one is opened to open second one? or via sperate buttons to activate each drawer?

Comment: @VivekSasidharan, in first drawer i have recycleview, on item click i want to open second drawer. both drawer have dynamic data and layout.

Comment: can you please share image what design you expect?

Comment: @MohitDholakia i want to slide another slider on first one with more data

Comment: You should use 1 DrawerLayout and 1 `androidx.slidingpanelayout.widget.SlidingPaneLayout`.